# Merge two branches together with production at the top

Tags: git

```
* 14a95c1        (HEAD) min base
* e69ca3b        (testminify, master) modified base
* 71863ae        added compressor
* 2d2bc01        added changes
* d000d45        merge fixes
* 18847ab        (production/master) added couple of cdns
* 8f02c19        minified css files
* 276649a        added libs
* f4b9533        fixed fb
* 2b4b490        prod ready
* 685a99c        removed dj static from settings file
* 1f012bc        added mailing support
* eb69d26        modified wsgi and static files
* bbd5c76        settings
* 39b229b        deleted some files
```

My git commit tree is as above, I want to merge *testminiy* and *production* together. 
I tried the following

```
git checkout production
```

then `git merge testminify`

but I am unable to get it working, I want the production branch to be at the top. Since I push production to the server. So I would like to have it as below, please let me know, what I am missing.

- 14a95c1        (HEAD production/master) min base
- e69ca3b        modified base
- 71863ae        added compressor
- 2d2bc01        added changes
- d000d45        merge fixes
- 18847ab        added couple of cdns
- 8f02c19        minified css files
- 276649a        added libs

Comment: You mention `production/master`, so it sounds like `production` is the name of the remote, not of a branch. Can you clarify?

Comment: yes production is the name of remote.

Comment: I missed the part about HEAD not being on master. Is it on a branch at all?

Comment: no it is not on a branch.

Answer (score 2):

With the example you provide, it looks like `production` is the name of the remote; `git remote` will list the remotes you have configured for that repository, and `git remote show production` will show details about the remote named `production`.

It seems like you have a local branch named `master`, which points to the same commit as `testminify`, so in other words it's already been merged in, at least locally. The `master` branch is (almost certainly) a local copy of the remote branch `production/master`.

What you need to do now is push your local changes to the remote. Your log suggests you'd need to do `git push production master` (push the changes made to the local `master` branch up to the `production` remote).

**Edit**: I had missed the part about the detached HEAD. In order to address this, you can reset master to point at that commit before you push:

```
git checkout -B master # master is now at 14a95c1
```

Comment: The commit at `HEAD` isn't pointed to by a branch though, I think the original poster wants that too.